# Writing to an image2DArray in a compute shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, compute-shader

I have a compute shader in which I'd like to write on the different layers of a `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` with `imageStore` but it doesn't work.

Here is the code I use to initialize my texture:

```
void Manager::initTextures(){
    texId = 0;

    GLsizei width = ofGetWidth();
    GLsizei height = ofGetHeight();
    GLsizei layerCount = NB_TEX;
    GLsizei mipLevelCount = 1;

    GLfloat texels[width*height*4*NB_TEX];
    for(int i = 0; i < width*height*4*NB_TEX; ++i){
        texels[i] = 1.0;
    }

    glGenTextures(1,&texId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,texId);

    glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, mipLevelCount, GL_RGBA32F, width, height, layerCount);

    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height, layerCount, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, texels);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);
}
```

Compute shader invocation (called at each frame):

```
void Manager::update(){
    cs.begin();
        glBindImageTexture(0, texId, 0, GL_TRUE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F);
        glUniform1i(cs.getUniformLocation("pathTex"), 0);
        cs.dispatchCompute(NB_TEX, 1, 1);
        glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);
    cs.end();
}
```

Compute shader:

```
#version 430

layout(rgba32f, binding=0) uniform coherent restrict image2DArray pathTex;

layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

void main(){
    imageStore(pathTex, ivec3(0, 0, 0), vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0));  
}
```

The compute shader doesn't seem to do anything.
However I can access all the layers of the texture in my fragment shader.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't do anything? It should write black to the bottom-left texel. That's probably not what you want though, this texture appears to be larger than 1x1.

Comment: Exactly, it should write a black pixel. But It doesn't work.

Comment: I managed a way to make it work but I still doesn't understand why this particular code doesn't work. In my fragment shader I bound the texture to a `sampler2DArray` and read it with `texture()`. I could read the texture but didn't see the changes made by the compute shader. Now I bind the texture to an `image2DArray` and read it with `imageLoad()` and it works.

Comment: I found my mistake, it was a stupid error of coordinates in the fragment shader...